# cmake - Is it possible to link executable to shared library with relative path at runtime?

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

Lets say I have this:

```
../project_dir
    main.cpp
    mylib.cpp
    mylib.h
```

Building steps will be:

```
g++ -c mylib.cpp -o mylib.o
g++ -shared -o libmylib.so mylib.o
g++ -L$(pwd) -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN' -o exec main.cpp -lmylib
```

`exec` will be my binary executable output. When I testing with:

```
ldd exec
```

the output line is:

```
libmylib.so => /full/path/to/build/directory/libmylib.so (0x00007f75fdd1f000)
```

That output line is my question, is it possible to get:

```
libmylib.so => ./libmylib.so
```

so whenever I move the executable file, I can move the shared library along with it. If it is possible, how to do this with cmake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you launch `ldd` to check your app shared library dependencies, it always prints absolute paths. But if you are using the `-rpath` oprtion together with the `$ORIGIN` variable, everything will work as you expect. You can move the executable and the shared library, remove the original build directory and you will still be able to launch your app.

This is how you can do it using `cmake`:

```
project(myapp)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(APP_SRC main.cpp)
set(LIB_SRC mylib.cpp)

link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS
          "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-rpath -Wl,$ORIGIN")

add_library(mylib SHARED ${LIB_SRC})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${APP_SRC})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} mylib)
```

Comment: Hardcoding compiler specific linker flags is a no-go for buildtool-generators (cmake). Setting global Compiler/Linker flags variables (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS) is a no-go.

Answer (score 6):

Juste add in your CMakefiles.txt

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE) # only if you want copy from the build tree
```

Comment: When I added the above two lines as well as the line above with $ORIGIN, this still failed:

    /usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/app.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /usr/bin/c++     -Wl,-rpath -Wl,$ORIGIN -rdynamic CMakeFiles/app.dir/app.cpp.o  -o app -Wl,-rpath,"\$ORIGIN"
    CMakeFiles/app.dir/app.cpp.o: In function `main':
    app.cpp:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `MyClass::app(std::string const&)'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    CMakeFiles/app.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'app' failed
    make[2]: *** [app] Error 1

Comment: CMake has been updated, so there are probably changes and these lines are certainly wrong now..
Sorry, I do not work against CMake anymore from years, so I am not aware about the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put curly braces around ${ORIGIN} and add path for the library to link:

```
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -L${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} -lmyLibrary -Wl,-rpath -Wl,${ORIGIN}")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${ORIGIN}")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
```